# A Firefox tool that shows object and element structure on hover?

Tags: html, firefox, layout

on any element in the webpage. I need to look at what the element and children elements are.

For e.g.

Answer (score 17):

[Firebug's](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) Inspect tool sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Also the [Web Developer extension](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) does a good job for DOM inspection...

Comment: Web Developer tool bar is great, you can turn bits on and off for testing as well as analysis the page.  I think its a wicked tool.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Firebug http://getfirebug.com

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the Firefox [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1806). In the app click the icon at the very top left, then on the desired element on the page, and it should scroll automatically to the relevant node in the DOM tree.